# Using Backup-SqlDatabase with Powershell to Remote machine

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-backups

I want to backup SQL Server using Powershell `Backup-SqlDatabase` command,
The problem is that I want to do it from a remote machine, and Backup-SqlDatabase has not IP address parameter.

Is there any way to use this command, or any other command to back up remotely the database.

I tried the following script:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "myPass" -AsPlainText -Force;
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("sa", $secpasswd);
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "192.168.65.149/sqlserver" -Database "ARM" -Credential $mycreds
```

where `sqlserver` is the instance of the Database, and `192.168.65.149` is the IP of the server

I got the following error:

```
Backup-SqlDatabase : Failed to connect to server 192.168.65.149/sqlserver.
At line:1 char:1
+ Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "192.168.65.149/sqlserver" -Databa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Backup-SqlDatabase], ConnectionFailureException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.BackupSqlDatabaseCommand
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes it does? It's the `-ServerInstance` switch. [`Backup-SqlDatabase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/backup-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps)

Comment: @Larnu -ServerInstance is not accepting the ip info, its getting the database server name, for example SQL-01\INSTANCE

Comment: `10.0.0.1/SqlExpress` and `srvSql/SqlExpress` are synonyms, if the IP representative of the server. Post the script your tried.

Comment: Can you see the connection attempt on the SQL servers's logs? I suspect you'll see something there. I'd also recommend against using the `sa` account for this. You should be using a user/login with adaquet permissions; preferably an AD account. Have you tried using the format in example 4 to see if the prompt for the password works? (`Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "Computer\Instance" -Database "MainDB" -Credential (Get-Credential "sa")`)

Comment: Have you enabled the remote connection in SQL Express? They are disabled by default. 
http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote-tcp-ip-connections-on-port-1433.aspx